# How to prevent concurrent login issue in asp.net application on different browser

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session

I have run the application using IE. It allows to login the application.After loggedin, I have copied the Url in IE and paste it into (different)chrome browser. It will allow to login.

wanted Output: It will not allow to login on different browser.. For example user already login..

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Panjanatham

Comment: It would be useful if you explained why you want to do this? It's normally accepted behaviour when using different browsers (or indeed the same browser with incognito sessions).

Comment: this fundamentally isn't how web applications work. You can try and do something like this but it's not very straightforward to control. Before you go down this complicated route...ask yourself this: **why** do you want to control this? What problem are you trying to prevent? Lots of applications and services allow you to be logged in from multiple devices/browsers/browser-sessions simultaneously. Why is it an issue for your application?

Comment: One of the main reasons not to do this is because people don;t have to explicitly log out of web sessions.  You would have to place some sort of timeout on the restriction.  There will undoubtedly be someone pissed off because they leave the office after using your site and then can't login on their tablet on the commute home.